# Programmatically set the resolution of image in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Does anyone have the experience in dealing with image resolutions? Is it possible doing with Iphone/ipad?

Comment: What do you mean 'resolution'? Assuming it's not a vector image, the resolution is defined already - do you mean scale (i.e. retain images?) or do you mean change the size it's rendered on the ui?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(UIImage*)processImageRect:(UIImage*)image:(CGSize)size:(CGSize)originalSize {
    // Draw image1  
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(originalSize);  
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height)]; 
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

   return resultingImage;
}

//This function will be helpful to you.
```